# Add new text form field when button pressed?

Tags: flutter

I have screen which have username field,

Here, When i press the submit button add new TextFormField below the UserName field so how i can do this?

Code as Below.

```
return Container(
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Text("Reset Password"),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Enter your username below to recieve password reset instruction",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: userNameController,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: "User Name",
              ),
              focusNode: fnField1,
              validator: (value) {
                if (value?.isEmpty == true) {
                  return AppLocalizations.of(context)!.valEnterUserName;
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
            Container(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {},
                child: Text("Submit"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Please help me that how i can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such a case we can use a `StatefulWidget` to set a `_displayNewTextField` boolean to `true` once the button is pressed:

```
bool _displayNewTextField = false;
...
Container(
  constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      setState(() {
        _displayNewTextField = true;
      });
    },
    child: const Text("Submit"),
  ),
),
```

And use a `Visibility` `Widget` to show the new `TextField` accordingly:

```
Visibility(
  visible: _displayNewTextField,
  child: TextFormField(
    controller: newTextFieldController,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      labelText: "User Name",
    ),
  ),
),
```

A full example is reported below:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _displayNewTextField = false;
  TextEditingController newTextFieldController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController userNameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Form(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: const Text("Reset Password"),
              ),
              const Center(
                child: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    "Enter your username below to recieve password reset instruction",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLines: 2,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: userNameController,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "User Name",
                ),
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: _displayNewTextField,
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: newTextFieldController,
                  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "User Name",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    setState(() {
                      _displayNewTextField = true;
                    });
                  },
                  child: const Text("Submit"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, It's works perfect.